# Mysql Join Query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization

I have two tables in mysql:

```
Results Table : 1046928 rows.
Nodes Table :  50 rows.
```

I am joining these two tables with the following query and the execution of the query is very very slow.

```
select res.TIndex, res.PNumber, res.Sender, res.Receiver, 
sta.Nickname, rta.Nickname from ((Results res join 
Nodes sta) join Nodes rta) where ((res.sender_h=sta.name) and
(res.receiver_h=rta.name));
```

Please help me optimize this query. Right now if I want to pull just top 5 rows, It takes about 5-6 MINUTES. Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE `nodes1` (
  `NodeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `Nickname` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NodeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `Results1` (
  `TIndex` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Sender` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `Receiver` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `PTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TIndex`,`PNumber`),
  KEY `PERIOD_TIME_IDX` (`PTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: post the SHOW CREATE TABLE output for the 2 tables

Comment: do you just mean the misspelling or is there something bigger im missing? i dont see anything logically wrong, just the `tra` vs `rta`

Comment: @jon_darkstar: That. I haven't looked closer.

Comment: My tables are really big. So, I just cutdown some columns and posted the smaller version. if you think real tables makes sence, I can post them as well. Thank you.

Comment: @M99: Please verify that the issue still exists with your stripped-down testcase. It's _good_ that you made one, but you should ensure that you made it properly. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  res.TIndex ,
        res.PNumber ,
        res.Sender ,
        res.Receiver ,
        sta.Nickname ,
        rta.Nickname
FROM    Results AS res
        INNER JOIN Nodes AS sta ON res.sender_h = sta.name
        INNER JOIN Nodes AS rta ON res.receiver_h = rta.NAME
```

1. Create an index on Results
   (sender_h)
2. Create an index on Results (receiver_h)
3. Create an index
   on Nodes (name)

Comment: +1  changing `where` clauses to join conditions and adding those indexes should make a big difference.  im guessing that with the full joins and where clauses a huge cartesian product gets created intermediately before its trimmed.  can anyone verify this or does it get optimized?

Comment: As far as i can tell, there isn't any real performance gain between WHERE over JOINS. I just prefer the JOIN syntax as it makes the meaning very clear. eg these are my table joins and these are my filters. All of the performance gains is by adding the indexes. You can retry your old query and it should run just as fast.

Answer (score 1):

Joining on the node's `name` rather than `NodeId` (the primary key) doesn't look good at all.

Perhaps you should be storing `NodeId` for foreign key `sender` and `receiver` in the `Results` table instead of `name`  Adding foreign key constraints is a good idea too.  Among other things, this might cause indexing automatically depending on your configuration

If this change is difficult, at the very least you should enforce uniqueness on `node`'s `name` field

If you change the tables definition in this manner, change your query to John's recommendation, and add indexes it should run a lot better and be a lot more readable/better form.